# What is the relationship between Goddess Cubes and Chests?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

What is the relationship between Goddess Cubes and Chests? Does each cube correspond to a specific chest, is it a sequence of chests or just unlocks random chests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each cube responds to a specific chest. [This guide](http://segmentnext.com/2011/11/20/zelda-skyward-sword-goddess-cubes-locations-and-chests-guide/) outlines where the cubes are, and the location of their corresponding chest.